# how to make first letter font increase only on the first paragraph

Tags: html

In my website document where i am using multiple paragraph,i want to make the first letter of the first paragraph font size increase.how to do that ?please help me.when i am making changes its reflecting on all paragraphs.

```
<p>This is my first paragraph</p>
<p>This is my second paragraph</p>
<p>This is my third paragraph</p>
```

I want to increase the size of 'T' alone in the first paragraph.
Please advice me how to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `first-letter` selector

```css
p:first-child:first-letter { 
        font-size: 40px;
    }
```

```html
<p>This is my first paragraph</p>
<p>This is my second paragraph</p>
<p>This is my third paragraph</p>
```

Comment: This applies to all paragraphs, not just the first.

Comment: Instead of the :first-child pseudo selector, try :first-of-kind

Comment: @nephiw do you mean `:first-of-type`?

Comment: @Sidsec9: thanks for your valuable inputs.But when i am copying the code to css..nothing happening .It appears to be the same.

Comment: p { 
 margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
p:first-child:first-letter { 
        font-size: 70px;
    }

Comment: Are you sure you've linked your CSS to your HTML?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with the whole code so that I can inspect it?

Comment: <body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="site_title">
 <h2>'a!</h2>
 <img class="image_wrapper image_fr "src="images/Logo_lockup.jpg" alt="image" />
    </div>
</div> 
<div id="menu">
       </div> 
<div id="main">
   <div class="inner_box last">
      <div class="col_w900_last">
      <div class="col_w420 lp_box float_l">
      <div class="inner_box">
     <h2>CHEMICALS</h2>
           <p>Cleaning products.. .</p>
      <h3>DID YOU KNOW</h3>
     <p>&#149; That parabens disrupt.....</p>

Comment: body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #ccc;
 font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1.5em; 
 background-color: #0093D0;
}



a, a:link, a:visited { 
 color: #c1d82f;
 text-decoration: none; 
 font-size: 15px;
}

a:hover { 
 text-decoration: underline; 
}

p { 
 margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
 padding: 0; 
}
p:first-child:first-letter { 
        font-size: 70px;
    }
img { border: none; }

Comment: This is not how you create a fiddle @hena, go here - https://jsfiddle.net/

Click save and then share your code

Comment: <style>p.intro::first-letter {
    color: #fff;
    font-size:40px;
}  
</style>                                                                                            HTML CODE:                                                                                        <p class="intro">This is an introduction.</p>
<p>This is a paragraph with some text. A bit more text even.</p>

Answer (score 0):

Surround the first character by a span tag, and style it so that the font size is bigger.

```
<p><span style="font-size:25px;">T</span>his is my paragraph</p>
```

Comment: This works only if the first letter is t, and a better way to do that still would be to wrap that in a `:before` pseudo-element.

Comment: It works with whatever text you place between the span tags. There very well might be better ways to do it. I'm not the most experienced when it comes to web development, but I figured I'd give it a shot anyways. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: @Venovani: thanks for your input.its working with my code.the thing is in my website it has many html pages ,so it will be better if i get some coding to be on css.It will save my time